# Please explain LINQ nested grouping

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm learning LINQ and have just met one very strange thing.
Here's the query:

```
    var queryNestedGroups =
    from student in students
    group student by student.Year into newGroup1
    from newGroup2 in
        (from student in newGroup1
         group student by student.LastName)
    group newGroup2 by newGroup1.Key;
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545974.aspx)

Theres no select clause, one group is grouped by another group, i just cant wrap my mind around this. Can you explain this query, or maybe demonstrate an equivalent query in SQL?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your first query executes i.e.

```
 from student in students
 group student by student.Year
```

This will return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Student>>` object that means, you will have multiple items (IEnumerable) of a group and that group consists of Key (student.Year which is of type `string`) and the objects which falls under that group (`Student` in this case).

Now since this `Student` object will itself be an `IEnumerable` (objects under each key(Year)), we are again quering it & since you need to again group this IEnumerable object with `LastName`, so again Step 1 will repeat i.e. it will again return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string,Student>>` object where Key will be 'student.LastName' & `Student` will be object with all students having lastname as Key:-

```
from student in newGroup1
group student by student.LastName
```

Now, Since our original object is supposed to group by `Year`, we are again grouping by `newGroup1.Key` which is nothing but `student.Year`.

Also, you don't need a select when query ends with a group by clause. Your LINQ query can end with either a select or group operator.

**Edit:-**
As per the example, Year is an Enum, so the return type will be slightly different by what I mentioned earlier, just run the below query and see the output:-

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<StudentClass.GradeLevel, StudentClass.Student>> group1 = 
                                                   from student in students
                                                   group student by student.Year;
```

Check this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CECciF), you will notice, that how students are grouped based on `Year`, but we want these students to be further grouped by `LastName`, so we used the [into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311045.aspx) keyword, which stores the output into a new identifier which can be queried further. So forget the initial result and now focus on the output we received from `group1` above, we need to group the students by LastName, and thus the inner query `(from student in newGroup1 group student by student.LastName)`, but remember we have to preserve the grouping we did in Step 1 i.e., we have to group the students by last name but only within each year, thus we are grouping this second query result by original Key i.e. 'Year'.

Comment: well.. the first part results in some { { Year1 { s1A, s1B, ... } }, { Year2 { s2A, s2B, ... } }, ... } collection, and the 2nd part in some { { LastNameA { sA1, sA2, ... } }, { LastNameB { sB1, sB2, ... } }, ... } collection. And then.. are these two collections joined? or whats going there? One of the tricky things here is how the first part is queried from the second part, may i think of the 1st part as of a common table expression in T-SQL?

Comment: ps is there an alternative for the use of the into operator? i've ended up with this query, can it be made simpler with no use of into?
http://i.gyazo.com/65a4c5621c96ee0a3d565cad46b7966d.png

Comment: @tsayper - Hey Whats wrong with `into` keyword? Its used to create a temporary result set which can be iterated over again, I am not sure why you want to omit that.

Comment: nothing wrong with it (its great!), i'm just curious